# Where can I get my Vietnam visa printed in Lak Sao, Laos?

Tags: visas, vietnam, e-visas, laos

I'm in Lak Sao, about 23km from the border crossing from Nam Phao Laos to Cau Treo Vietnam. My e-visa was just granted and I'll cross the border in two days.

[I read on the official e-visa site that I should get a printout of my visa.](https://evisa.xuatnhapcanh.gov.vn/khai-thi-thuc-dien-tu/cap-thi-thuc-dien-tu)

Lak Sao is pretty small. Mainly vehicle repair places, local import export businesses, and a local market.

My guesthouse doesn't have a printer. When I was exploring the other day it looked like even the post office is closed at the moment. I went back today and though it seemed to be kind of open, the man apparently working, once he understood what I wanted said he couldn't help.

There's a tourist office that looks like it went dormant some time during the pandemic:
[image: Tourist office in Lak Sao]

Does anybody know who/where in this town I might be able to get my visa printed?

A place in Na Pe (village half-way), or at the border crossing on the Lao side is also acceptable.

Comment: Tried using google maps to locate a print shop? It can be any photo studio, DTP center, internet cafe, etc.

Comment: @AnishSheela Yes I did. There are print shops over on the Vietnam side or maybe way back in the previous town I stayed at. Many businesses still in Google Maps closed during the pandemic and haven't been removed yet too, which is annoying.

Comment: @hippietrail don’t forget to send updates to Google Maps about those

Comment: I've been doing a fair few Google Maps updates lately!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't need to print out your visa if you cross here. There were three people I had to show my passport and e-visa to, and there was absolutely no problem with it being on my phone.

Make sure you'll be able to access the PDF without Internet access. My default PDF app needed internet access to view a PDF stored on my phone! Fortunately I also had Google's "Files" app which could view it. I also had a photo of it on my laptop screen in case.

I spent a couple of hours the day before walking around Lak Sao looking for some kind of office. The post office was not helpful. The guy at my guesthouse seemed baffled. Friendly people at the restaurant I ate at every day didn't know a place. I did not ask at any pharmacy, that may work. There were a couple of package delivery companies. I didn't ask them but they may also be a possibility.

For other border crossings I can't promise the PDF of the e-visa on your phone will work.

Comment: In many cases there is advice to print things you have on your phone just in case your phone won’t work (no battery or issues like the one you mentioned). I wonder if that’s the same logic here.

Comment: Good point. I didn't think of that.